# When does a matrix with high rank have a minor with disjoint rows and columns and high rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinants

This is a somewhat open-ended followup question to 
[Does an antisymmetric matrix with high rank have a minor with disjoint rows and columns and high rank?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336222/does-an-antisymmetric-matrix-with-high-rank-have-a-minor-with-disjoint-rows-and) and [Does a non-singular matrix have a large minor with disjoint rows and columns and full rank?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331580/does-a-non-singular-matrix-have-a-large-minor-with-disjoint-rows-and-columns-and)

Let $A$ be an $n$-by-$n$ matrix of high rank -- say rank $n$ (i.e., $A$ is non-singular). Under which conditions do we know that $A$ has an $m$-by-$m$ non-singular minor with $m$ large and the sets of row and column indices of $A$ disjoint?

(One example of a valid condition is skew-symmetry; then the statement holds with $m=n/2$.)

Comment: Maybe obvious, but useful as a starting point: the identity matrix has rank $n$, but all of its submatrices with disjoint row and column indices are zero.

Comment: Yes - and there are other, less obvious counterexamples. Perhaps I should add them here.

Comment: Besides things like $\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\1 & 1 & 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$, there is also  $\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & a & a\\1 & a & 0 & a\\1 & a & a & 0\end{matrix}\right)$.